# Can a class inherit from 2 different classes?

Tags: sql, class, abstract-class

I have 5 classes (I simplified them a little here):

```
----------
| Person | 
----------
| Id     |
| Name   |
| Email  |
----------

-----------------
| Student       |
-----------------
| StudentId     |
| StudentNumber |
| PersonId      |
-----------------

-----------------
| Teacher       |
-----------------
| TeacherId     |
| TeacherNumber |
-----------------

-----------------
| Patient       |
-----------------
| PatientId     |
| PatientNumber |
-----------------

----------------
| Doctor       |
----------------
| DoctorId     |
| DoctorNumber |
----------------
```

I want to be able to add a Doctor or a Patient. The other classes can be seen as abstract.

A Patient or Doctor can either be a Student or a Teacher, but is always a Person.

These are the 4 outcomes that should be possible:

```
Person > Teacher > Doctor
Person > Teacher > Patient
Person > Student > Doctor
Person > Student > Patient
```

What is the best way to tackle this?
I also need to know before I create my database.

I have thought about adding a TeacherDoctor, TeacherPatient, StudentDoctor and StudentPatient class, but this seems inefficient.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you need this separation? In a database, this is usually viewed as a mistake because some of your *data* has instead been modelled as *metadata*, embedded in the table names rather than just being a column in a single table. Without knowing more about your model, it seems two boolean properties in Person, "IsTeacher" and "IsDoctor" may be sufficient.

Comment: I see you point, but does this mean I should give the person class a StudentNumber, TeacherNumber, PatientNumber and DoctorNumber, but just leave some empty if they dont apply to them? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you developing in? Different languages have different ways of handling multiple inheritance.

Also, are you using any persistence technology?

For example, in Java, a class can inherit from multiple interfaces, and there are ways to map that to your database in JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET with MVC. For my database I use MSSQL